# "Could not resolve 'proxyhost'" when I run sudo apt-get update in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, package-management, proxy

`sudo apt-get update` isn't working for me in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

```
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not resolve 'proxyhost'
Err:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'proxyhost'
Err:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Could not resolve 'proxyhost'
Err:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Could not resolve 'proxyhost'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not resolve 'proxyhost'
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'proxyhost'
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'proxyhost'
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Could not resolve 'proxyhost'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: do you have a proxy configured in apt: `grep -i proxy $(find /etc/apt -type f)`

Comment: after doing that also happening samee...!.

Comment: That command wouldn't have changed anything - it should just tell you if you have a proxy configured in apt.conf[.d].  Was there any output?